# Reading into an array but every time i read into the array it rewrites over it and only prints the last entered value

Tags: python, spyder

I am new to coding I am trying to read into an array from a textbox but each time I enter a new value that value is set to 0 and writes over the last entered value. I am refering to the def submit function

```
from tkinter import *


def submit():
    
    data=[]
    while True:
        entry = str(textBox.get())
        print("*"+entry+"*")
        data.append(entry)
        print("#"+entry+"#")
        textBox.delete(0,END)
        print(data)
        if entry == "":
            print(data) 
        break
    
        
gui1 = Tk()
gui1.title("Main Screen")
gui1.geometry("800x500")
gui1.config(bg="black")

submit = Button(gui1,text="submit",command=submit) 
submit.pack(side = BOTTOM, padx=5,pady = 5)

label = Label(gui1, text = "Enter name: ")
label.config(font=("Consolas",15))
label.pack(side=LEFT,padx=50, pady=50)

textBox = Entry()
textBox.config(font=('Ink Free',15)) #change font
textBox.config(bg="White") #background
textBox.config(fg="Red") #foreground
textBox.config(width=50) #width displayed in characters
#textBox.insert(0,'Spongebob') #set default text
#textBox.config(state=DISABLED) #ACTIVE/DISABLED
#textBox.config(show='*') #replace characters shown with x character
textBox.pack(side= LEFT,padx=25,pady=25)


gui1.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because you have initialized the **data** inside the submit function, just initialize it above the submit function and you will  have the desired output

```
data=[]
def submit():
  
    while True:
        entry = str(textBox.get())
        print("*"+entry+"*")
        data.append(entry)
        print("#"+entry+"#")
        textBox.delete(0,END)
        print(data)
        if entry == "":
            print(data) 
        break
```

[Output can be seen by clicking the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuvWG.png)

Comment: Thank you so much I really appreciate the help